# How to make an ArrayList on a PlayerJoinEvent

Tags: java, bukkit

How would I make a new `ArrayList` per player when the first join a server (`PlayerJoinEvent`), so each player has an `ArrayList` (for friends list plugin)?

I am want an `ArrayList`, or any other `List` to be made with the new player's name, and their friends list as the list name

I want this list to be open for command adding so a player can add friends from the server to there friends list. I just don't know how I would make a `PlayerJoinEvent` create a list based on the player.

Answer (score 3):

To create an `ArrayList`, you could use:

```
List<UUID> players = new ArrayList<UUID>();
```

But, I'm pretty sure that you're talking about a [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) when you say that you would like to store a list of friends for players. So, you could use:

```
Map<UUID, List<UUID>> players = new HashMap<UUID, List<UUID>>();
```

A [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) is like a collection of variables based on a key. In the above case, for every `UUID` put into the map, there will be a `List<UUID>` as the value.

Make sure to *NEVER* use the `Player` object as a type parameter in an `ArrayList`, `HashMap`, `HashSet`, or anything like that. Doing this will cause memory leaks when the player leaves the server, making the server very, very laggy after a lot of people leave.

To fix this, you could use the player's `UUID`:

```
UUID id = player.getUniqueId();
```

or their name:

```
String name = player.getName();
```

So, here's what your code could look like:

```
Map<UUID, List<UUID>> players = new HashMap<UUID, List<UUID>>();

@EventHandler
public void playerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e){
  UUID uuid = e.getPlayer().getUniqueId();
  //get the player's friends here, if they have none, keep the
  //new ArrayList<UUID>(); otherwise, don't
  List<UUID> friends = new ArrayList<UUID>();
  players.add(uuid);
}
```

Make sure to put the above code in a class that `implements Listener`:

```
public class PlayerJoinListener implements Listener{
  //...
}
```

Also, make sure to register events in your `onEnable()` in your `Main` class (the one that `extends JavaPlugin`):

```
@Override
public void onEnable(){
  //replace PlayerJoinListener with whatever your Listener class is
  this.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, new PlayerJoinListener());
}
```

Then, whenever you want to get the list of a player's friends, you could use [`HashMap.get()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get(java.lang.Object)):

```
UUID uuid = player.getUniqueId();
List<UUID> friends = players.get(uuid);
```

Then, if you wanted to set the player's friend list to a new value, you could use [`HashMap.put()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put(K,%20V)):

```
List<UUID> newFriendsList = new ArrayList<UUID>();
players.put(uuid, newFriendsList);
```

So, if you wanted to add a player to another player's friends list, you could use:

```
public void addToFriendsList(Player player, Player friend){
    //get the unique ids
    UUID uuid = player.getUniqueId();
    UUID friendID = friend.getUniqueId();

    //update the player's friends list and add "friend"
    List<UUID> friends = players.get(uuid);
    friends.add(friendID);

    //put the list back into the HashMap
    players.put(uuid, friends);
}
```

If you wanted to store the player's friends in a [`config`](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Configuration_API_Reference) file, you could use:

```
UUID uuid = player.getUniqueId();
String key = "Friends." + uuid.toString();
config.set(key, players.get(uuid));
```

to set the player's friends (or update them), and use this to get them:

```
UUID uuid = player.getUniqueId();
String key = "Friends." + uuid.toString();
List<String> friends = config.getStringList(key);
//this is a list of the friend's UUIDs as strings
```

Comment: And these would fire on a new player join event so they have an arraylist under there name that can then have other names added to it?

Comment: @3xiledgooru If you want to add other player names to the player's name, you should use a `HashMap`. I'll update my answer on how to use them

Comment: in this code section will it name the list based on the list owners name, then allow friends to be added. im sorry if i have repeated my self im just not seeing that happen in here.

Comment: and where would i find these lists so i can check there content if im not in game, would it be in a config file?

Comment: @3xiledgooru This won't do anything but store it locally, like you asked in your question. Adding config support to it, you would have to do something like `config.set("Friends." + player.getName(), players.get(player.getUniqueId()))` to set friends, and get friends, `config.getStringList("Friends." + player.getName())`

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like:

```
ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();

public void addPlayer(PlayerJoinEvent e) {
    Player p = e.getPlayer();
    players.add(p);
}
```